# How to show Tooltip on AxisLabels usign ng2-charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have wrapped X-Axis label text with "..." and now I have to show tooltip when user will hover on it with full text. Please help.

Here is the example with wrapped text : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example-epwz36 and here is ticket request which is done by some one else to add plugin https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3907

for more clear please check attached screenshot:
[image]